# UrbanAirship: Device listing API returns far many device tokens than actually registered

Tags: push-notification, urbanairship.com

We have an app setup with UrbanAirship. UrbanAirship shows (under Reports->Statistics) we have approx 1.5M devices registered.

We want to switch to internal push notification service and thus want to export device token ids from UAS. For this, I'm using Device Listing API of UAS to export the device token ids:
http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/device_information.html#device-token-list-api

I'm using REST client that is provided by UAS for making underlying REST calls. I'm paginating  through device tokens to retrieve all the device tokens. My php code is still running and has gathered around 46M tokens till now.

Am I making any mistake using Device Listing API? Did anybody use Device Listing API successfully to retrieve device tokens from UAS?

I'm pasting my code in PHP which is retrieving and printing the tokens. This uses their PHP REST client that is provided by UAS in their documentation.

```
public function getTokens() {
    $this->client = new Airship($app_key, $app_secret);
    $airshipDeviceList = $this->client->get_device_tokens();
    //print_r($airshipDeviceList->count());
    //exit;

    $i = 0;
    while(true) {
        $current_page = $airshipDeviceList->_page;
        print_r($current_page);
        exit;

        if(isset($current_page->device_tokens)) {
            $tokens = $current_page->device_tokens;

            foreach($tokens as $token) {
                print_r("\n $i : ");
                print_r($token->device_token);
                $i++;
            }
            $next_page_url = $current_page->next_page;
            $airshipDeviceList->_load_page($next_page_url);
        } else {
            break;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. "$current_page" was not really paginating over tokens. It was actually aggregating N+1 pages (last all pages plus current page). As a result, I was getting n tokens in first page, 2n tokens in second page, 3n tokens in third page and so on.

I changed REST library from UAS and fixed it to return ONLY CURRENT PAGE tokens in $current_page.
Problem solved!